# Развернуть JAVA WEB приложение в интернет

Tags: spring, tomcat, веб-программирование, развертывание

Написал web приложение (сайт), используя фрейморки SPRING IoC, MVC, Security, Hibernate и БД MySQL. Запускаю локально из-под Tomcat8 в Intell IDEA.

Как выложить его в нэте, чтобы оно функционировало как самостоятельный сайт?

Comment: А разве со своего компа нельзя сделать сервер и запустить свое web-java-приложение для общего доступа с любого удаленного устройства и браузера???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя хостинг или домашний сервер?

Если хостинг, то надо выбирать VPS, на обычных не держат ни java, ни tomcat.
А VPS - это как свой собственный компьютер, делай с ним что хочешь.

Далее, независимо от того домашний сервер или VPS, устанавливается всё необходимое: java, tomcat, mysql.
Изучается руководство по tomcat на предмет того, куда там складываются общие библиотеки, и по необходимости туда кидается всякое: драйвер jdbc для mysql, hibernate, spring.
Потом находим в какую папку размещать свои war-архивы. Закинул туда и всё готово.

Как найти сайт tomcat через google надо описывать?

Если vps на линухе, то выбирайте линух такой, чтобы там нормальная java от oracle устанавливалась без танцев с бубеном (если конечно не доверяете openjdk)
А линух реально лучше. Он больше памяти может отдать приложениям, что для java важно. Если не жалко раскошелиться за дополнительный гиг памяти для самой виндовс, то можно и виндовс.

Есть один хостинг, где для java много чего заготовлено. Есть предустановленные сервера приложений, базы данных на выбор. Есть бесплатный тариф, но не знаю на время или на всегда. https://www.openshift.com/

Comment: спасибо. начинает проясняться. хотелось бы на хостинге. tomcat смогу найти) я сам понимаю, что мой вопрос прозвучал немного вульгарно, но когда нет опыта - теряешься в банальных вещах.